# How to catch duplicates?

Tags: excel, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm importing Excel into postgreSQL. The address column in Excel has duplicates which I want to catch. What is the most feasible way to go about.

```
import psycopg2
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("data.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("List")
database = psycopg2.connect (database = "Excel", user="SQL", password="PASS", host="YES", port="DB")
cursor = database.cursor()
delete = """Drop table if exists "Python".list"""
print (delete)
mydata = cursor.execute(delete)
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE "Python".list
   (DCAD_Prop_ID    varchar(50),
Address varchar(50),
Addition varchar(50),
Block   varchar(50),
Lot integer,
Project_ID integer
   );''')
print "Table created successfully"
query = """INSERT INTO "Python".list (DCAD_Prop_ID, Address,Addition,Block  ,Lot,Project_ID)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    DCAD_Prop_ID = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    Address = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    Addition = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    Block = sheet.cell(r,3).value   
    Lot = sheet.cell(r,4).value 
    Project_ID = sheet.cell(r,5).value
values = (DCAD_Prop_ID, Address,Addition,Block  ,Lot,Project_ID)
cursor.execute(query, values)
cursor.close()
database.commit()
database.close()
print ""
print "All Done! Bye, for now."
print ""
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)
print "I just imported Excel into postgreSQL"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return duplicated rows:

```
select DCAD_Prop_ID, Address,Addition,Block,Lot,Project_ID, count(*)
from "Python".list
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
having count(*) > 1
```

To eliminate duplicates in Python use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
>>> t = ((1,2),(2,3),(1,2))
>>> set(t)
set([(1, 2), (2, 3)])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Clodoaldo. This is at the SQL level I want to catch the duplicates when I run the program in Python. Is that possible in Python?

Comment: @PLearner Sure. Use a set as in the edited question.

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo. How would I apply the SET in the original script. Would it be something like Address = set(sheet.cell(r,1).value)?

Comment: You need to first read all rows from Excel appending them to the set. Then in another loop insert into Postgresql.

Comment: Thanks for not down voting my question @ Clodoaldo.